Is 67 mA enough for driving IRFP460 at 19 kHz?

I designed this circuit to drive 311 V loads from an ESP32 using IRFP460 MOSFETs and TLP250 optocouplers. However, the isolated DC-DC converter (B0515S-1WR3) can only supply around 67 mA. Using I = Q/t (19 kHz frequency), I calculated a gate current of 2.87 mA, so well within 67 mA, but I'm not sure if my calculations are correct.

Have you tried using a simulator and testing the results that way?

@Andyaka I don't think they have all my components in a simulator, at least not in Falstad

TLP250 supplies 1.5A peak, for short durations. The bigger problems are:

You don't show any bypass capacitors on them, which will create problems.
The fast switching will develop large transient voltage at turn-off, and transmit EMI up the wires (assuming they're more than a meter or so in length, or placed near other long wires).  Peak voltage increases power dissipation, and may affect reliability (IRFP460 is one of the few types rated for repetitive avalanche, so it may be serviceable, but still not recommended).
The FWB appears to be wired backwards (or you intend the loads to be on all the time, but that would be strange).

There are also concerns with transient mains voltage, inrush current (depending on load characteristics), and the resistor values are illegible so it's not clear what drive strength you intended.
You are correct, using Qg(tot) * Fsw * 3, calculates the DC current consumption, which is generally small.  The power supply won't limit on peak loads; that's drawn from the supply bypass capacitors instead.  (Which is part of why the TLP250s need local bypass.)  You should also use a ground plane underneath the active area, to ensure low ground impedance and low stray inductance.

The load is a LED string light and the circuit is on a PCB so short wires. The bridge rectifier looks good to me, why are you saying it's wired backwards? Also, about bypass caps, where should I place them?

You have the negative wired to the loads, thus sinking current from the MOSFETs, and the intrinsic body diode (shown twice on the schematic: the triangle in the middle pointing from source to channel, and the explicit parallel diode from source to drain) always conducts in this direction, hence the loads will be always-on. The datasheet says what value and placement for bypass caps. Keep the path from TLPs to MOSFETs similarly short.

I connected the loads to the "+" sign on the rectifier. Don't know if it is visible on this picture.

Unless the wires are crossing in a way I can't see, the diodes are pointing away from the common supply, making that node negative.

You are right, the wires were reversed. Is this better? Also, the load is only 0.2A at most, so I hope there won't be large transient voltages.

Yes, that wiring is correct. Such large transistors for such small loads? You may have trouble getting PWM linearity, at that frequency. The added capacitor pairs are peculiar; an R+C snubber might be most reasonable, exact values of which depend on load characteristic and wiring length, but ballpark values of say 1nF + 100R might be a starting point. A polarized (electrolytic) type is definitely not needed there.

Something like this?
